NCryptOpenStorageProvider return NTE_DEVICE_NOT_READY with TPM sometimes?
I've using win32 api NCryptOpenStorageProvider to store key pair on Windows with TPM, like:
status = NCryptOpenStorageProvider(provider, MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER, 0);

I found that some machine will return NTE_DEVICE_NOT_READY, but it works successfully sometimes.
Does anybody know why?

probably besause tpm device really not ready

So it has strong connection with TPM? I wanna confirm that if this problem will happen if I just use MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER.

what is "strong connection" ? provider via tbs.dll open file on tpm device and do some operations on it. i can not say why and where was fail, without debug concrete system

'strong conection' I mean: this error code only occurs when I pass MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER parameter. If I do not use TPM, just use MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, this error will not appear?

Besides, can i make it ready by waiting for some time? how can i make it ready QAQ

Yes, this error can be only in case MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER, you never got in with MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER. By waiting - I don't know. I never view by self such situation and can't say without research on concrete system
